# Find row with closest value

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have a very large pandas dataframe with two columns, A and B. For each row containing values a and b in columns A and B respectively, I'd like to find another row with values a' and b' so that the absolute difference between a and a' is as small as possible. I would like to create two new columns: a column containing the "distance" between the two rows (i.e., abs(a - a')), and a column containing b'.

---

Here are a couple of exmaples. Let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 5, 7, 2, 3, 4], 'B' : [5, 2, 7, 5, 1, 9]})
```

The first row has `(a, b) = (1, 5)`. The two new columns for
this row would contain the values `1` and `5`. Why? Because the closest value to `a = 1` is `a' = 2`, which occurs in the fourth row. The value of `b'` in that row is `5`.

The second row has `(a, b) = (5, 2)`. The two new columns for this row would contain the values `1` and `9`. The closest value to `a = 5` is `a' = 4`, which occurs in the last row. The corresponding value of `b'` in that row is `9`.

If the value of `a'` that minimizes `(a - a')` isn't unique, ties can be broken arbitrarily (or you can keep all entries).

---

I believe I need to use the `pandas.merge_asof` function, which allows for approximate joining. I also think that I need to set  `merge_asof` function's `direction` keyword argument to `nearest`, which will allow selecting the closest (in absolute distance) to the left dataframe's key.

I've read the entire documentation (with examples) for pandas.merge_asof, but forming the correct query is a little bit tricky for me.

Comment: Is it possible that two rows might have the same `a` value?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, it's much easier to assume they're distinct, it would still be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `allow_exact_matches=False` and `direction='nearest'` parameters, last for `A1` subtract `A` column with absolute values:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('A')
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df1.rename(columns={'A':'A1', 'B':'B1'}), 
                   left_on='A', 
                   right_on='A1', 
                   allow_exact_matches=False, 
                   direction='nearest')

df['A1'] = df['A1'].sub(df['A']).abs()
print (df)
   A  B  A1  B1
0  1  5   1   5
1  2  5   1   5
2  3  1   1   5
3  4  9   1   1
4  5  2   1   9
5  7  7   2   2
```

Comment: I think OPs expectation for the `A1` column is `[1,1,1,1,1,2]`

Comment: Yeah, that is right @Nick.

Comment: @Joey - Can you add expected ouput DataFrame to question?

Comment: Okay sure @jezrael

Comment: @Joey - because first 2 rows match  a=2, b=5 and for second a=4, b=9.

Comment: The first two rows don't match. For example, the first row differs. I would expect the two new columns to contain `1` and`5`, respectively. It looks like the second column (B1) is correct though. The first column should contain the minimal distance from `a` to some other value `a'` (both of which are from column A)